# SQL how to perform calculations on float time and string time?

Tags: sql, db2, subtraction

Hi I have table in DB2:

```
ID       TIME1        TIME2       
1000     480.5        30:30:00
```

I want to get TIME1-TIME2

```
ID       TIME1-TIME2 
1000       450.0
```

TIME1 is decimal value in HOURS- so 480.5 hours.
TIME2 is string value: 30:30:00 (30hours 30minutes 00 seconds)

How to get this subtraction?

Thank you!

Comment: ... Storing interval data in two _different_ datatypes is terrible.  Actually, this would be the perfect case for creating some user-defined types, which would then give you nice type-safety, and probably allow you to just use them in date arithmetic 'normally'.

Comment: This is from my customer database and I can not do it anything about it or change types in their database so this definitely is not a solution

Answer (score 2):

You have before to convert the two fields (the string and the decimal fields) to an INTERVAL data type and then perform the subtract operation. Take a look at [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/adding_an_interval_data_type44?lang=en) that explains how to handle interval in DB2 .

Using function that you will find in that article you can arrange a solution in this way for example :

```
SELECT ID, 
NUMTODSINTERVAL(TIME1, 'SECOND') - TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || TIME2) AS TIME1-TIME2 
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks for response but there are to many functions. Not sure which to use and does I have to do it on both fields? Can you write me just an example? thanks,regards

Comment: Take a look at the example that i have posted should works even i haven't tried it ...

Comment: Thanks for effort.I am getting error at NUMTODSINTERVAL function I hope that is not the problem that I am getting TIME1 with this expression (dec (( timestampdiff(
  4, 
  char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2))  and TIME2 is from some other table T2. which I successfully joined with mine. So expression will be NUMTODSINTERVAL((dec (( timestampdiff(
  4, 
  char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2)), 'SECOND') - TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || T2.TIME2)